# Compile Error and correct Syntax

Tags: java

Here is my code; apparently I am missing main. Please help

```
class A {

    A get(){return this;}

}


class B1 extends A{
    B1 get(){return this;}
    void message(){System.out.println("welcome to covariant return type");}

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new B1().get().message();
    }
}
```

Comment: More likely you are not running the program correctly. e.g. are you running `java -cp . B1` ? I suggest you try running (and formatting your code) in your IDE.

Comment: @MichalWilkowski, B1 must be declared public and you are right. Nothing has changed since you have learned java specs :)..

Comment: I have no idea why he deleted the post.

Answer (score 1):

**Class A**

```
public class A
{
    public A get()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

**Class B1**

```
public class B1 extends A
{
    public B1 get()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public void message()
    {
        System.out.println("welcome to covariant return type");
    }
}
```

**Main method**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     B1 b1 = new B1();
     B1 b2 = b1.get();

     b2.message();
}
```

If you write it out like this, it's a bit clearer for you and for others to read. The `main` method should be enclosed in a class, but I separated it out so you can see each component of your code.

Comment: The main method has to be inside some class.